# Preventing form from submition on autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/web/projects/add" id="EventAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div> 
    <div class="input text">
        <label for="AddressSearch">Search address</label>
        <input name="adress_search" type="text" id="AddressSearch"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="EventAddress">Address</label>
        <input name="data[Event][address]" type="text" id="EventAddress"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="EventPostNr">Post nr</label>
        <input name="data[Event][post_nr]" type="text" id="EventPostNr"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="EventCity">City</label>
        <input name="data[Event][city]" type="text" id="EventCity"/>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <input  type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The previously mentioned fields are used for choosing autosuggested addresses by google maps and I omit that code for better readability, but the problem appears when the autosuggest dropdown appears. If a users navigates to one of the suggestion by keyboard and presses `enter`, the whole form is submitted. I have the following function to prevent the form from submition on mouse click:

```
jQuery('#EventAddForm').submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $("#AddressSearch").is(":focus") ||
    $("#EventPostNr").is(":focus") ||
    $("#EventCity").is(":focus"))
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

But what I want to do is to prevent the form on the `enter` click as well.

I lack some knowledge in jQuery and just cannot get it running, so any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to specify all the fields in case they change.

Instead use a more generic selector.

```
jQuery('#EventAddForm').submit(function( event ) {
    if ($(this).find('input:text:focus').length) event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KpXD3/

Comment: Just tried that, but the form is still being submitted.

Comment: This works in isolation (see the jsfiddle). Have you looked at your console to check there is nothing preventing your JS from working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this condition to your if block:

```
jQuery('#EventAddForm').submit(function( event ) {
    if ( $("#AddressSearch").is(":focus") ||
      $("#EventPostNr").is(":focus") ||
      $("#EventCity").is(":focus") ||
      event.which == 13) //13 is code for enter key
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Should also `return false` for compatibility.

Comment: I removed my +1 for the added `return false` line. @AshleyMedway What compatibility are you returning false for?

Comment: Removed `return false` since `event.preventDefault();` is compatible across browsers.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja IE6, IE7 and occasionally it's needed in IE8. You could  also use `event.returnValue = false` for the ultimate of support.

Comment: Just tried that in chrome, and the form is still being submitted.